# Gitlab CI pre-defined variable not available in merge request pipeline

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run a pipeline on merge request events when changes to certain files were made. However, when I add the `rules` configuration for this, I keep getting the error `Failed to parse rule for test-job: rules:changes:compare_to is not a valid ref`.

I cannot seem to figure out why `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` is unavailable. I have a similar job with nearly the same configuration and in that case the variable is available.

My job is as follows:

```yaml
test-job:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"
      changes:
        paths:
          - folder/*
          - folder/important_subfolder/**/*
        compare_to: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME
  needs: []
  image:
    name: alpine/latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - cd folder
  script:
    - echo ${CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME}
```

If I run this job without the `rules`, it will correctly `echo` the target branch name. However, with the rules included it never runs due to `yaml errors` that I mentioned above.

The only logical conclusion is that I'm not in a merge_request pipeline, but I don't see how that's possible since I have another job that uses the same `rule` (only with different paths) that works fine.

Anyone had similar issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior for `rules:changes:` comparisons on merge request pipelines is to use the target branch for comparison, so you should just omit the `compare_to:` parameter entirely and that will provide the behavior you want.

The reason why you're seeing this error is because `rules:changes:compare_to:` [does not support variable expansion](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/369916). Hence, the value is interpreted as the *literal string* `$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME` which is obviously not a valid git ref.

Comment: Ah, correct! I found the explanation of the default `compare_to:` value in [this comment](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/293645) . I'm not extra unsure why the other pipeline does work with this rule configuration but I'll leave that for what it is. Thanks for the answer!